# re-size the lablel based on the text size in SWT

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a label where i initially place a static text.During the course of my application I will be overwriting this label by using setText method on it and the size of the text may vary.How to re-size the size of the label instead of placing a constant size in the begining

```
Label fontDisplay;
fontDisplay = new Label(Composite, SWT.NONE);
GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.widthHint = 12;
    fontDisplay.setLayoutData(gridData);
 ....

 fontDisplay(someText);//size of some text is greater than 12,how to re -size the label here?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`Control#pack()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#pack()) on the parent of the `Label`:

```
private static final String TEXT = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Randomize");

    final Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("abc");

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        private Random random = new Random();

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            label.setText(TEXT.substring(0, random.nextInt(TEXT.length())));
            label.getParent().pack();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the answert.We just have to call the layout of the widget's parent.It does the trick.

```
  Composite.layout(true);
```